# Why can't I edit user privileges in pgAdmin 4?

Tags: postgresql, privileges, pgadmin-4

Everything is in the title: I can't edit user privileges in pgAdmin 4.

To be more precise: I launch pgAdmin 4, enter the global password, enter the server password, click on `Login/Group Roles`, click on the user for which I want to edit the privileges, click on `Properties`, then `Edit`, then `Privileges` and here is the issue, I cannot edit anything, it's like disabled.

Any idea on how to solve that ?

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add the `grant` or `revoke` statements you are running and the exact error message you get.

Comment: No, everything is not in the title.  what menu are you using?  What happens?  Is it greyed out?  Does it throw an error?  Does your computer burst into flames?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I edited the question. I cannot run any statements.

Comment: to run a SQL statement you need to open the query editor

Comment: @jjanes Yes it's like greyed out/disabled/impossible to edit.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name The Query Tool is also disabled/greyed out.

Comment: Are you a superuser?  Unless you are a superuser, most things will be greyed out.

Comment: @jjanes It was a superuser issue, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I was connecting to the server with a non superuser role. So before connecting to the server, edit its connection settings with username `postgres` or any other superuser and it should be good.

Many thanks to @jjanes for pointing me in the right direction.